# how to show design layout right side my xml code in android stdio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

> i try to showing desing layout side my code. exmple
>   I have

my android stdio screen

[image]

I want to another screen for example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the `Preview` under `Gradle` in right side of `Android Studio`.

You can live preview the code but can not view the interaction like press a `Button` or any other interaction effect. To view this interaction effect you must run your app in emulator.

See the pic for clearly understand.

[image]

Comment: Question, it somehow is split at the bottom of my screen, how do i get it to go back to the right side of the like in the image!?

Comment: In the recent version of Android Studio(Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 This version I'm using now), I hope you will get Code, Split, and Design views in the top right side of android studio. Open an XML file then click split to preview the XML layout. You can also get preview of different devices in layout validation under Gradle in right side of android studio.

Comment: @Learn2Code if your preview is at the bottom, below your code, then press the split button one more time and it will restore to the right side, press it again will go again at the bottom etc. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Layout Preview pane?

When you have opened your xml layout go to 
`View -> Tool Window -> Preview`

Answer (score 1):

If your android studio is version up to 4, then just click the split button.
Then you can see the preview of the code and design layout.

**See the pic for clearly understand.**

[image]